# layout rendering issue

Tags: magento2, module, layout, blocks, tabs

I'm getting following issue when I'm click associated products.

```
main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_321f776dd692abd332ec2bb61e502b692 and handles default, attachments_attachments_attachment_products: Please correct the XML data and try again. complex type 'handleType', attribute 'base': The QName value 'layoutType' does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition.
Line: 47
 [] []
[2016-07-15 13:35:01] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_3cf9ab1b1723bedc1dcd665a812b00335 and handles admin-1column: Please correct the XML data and try again. complex type 'handleType', attribute 'base': The QName value 'layoutType' does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition.
Line: 47
 [] []
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="root">
      <block class="Web4pro\Attachments\Block\Adminhtml\Attachment\Edit\Tab\Product" name="attachment.edit.tab.product"/>
      <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="product_grid_serializer">
        <reference name="product_grid_serializer">
          <action method="initSerializerBlock">
            <arguments>
              <argument xsi:type="string" name="grid_block_name">attachment.edit.tab.product</argument>
              <argument xsi:type="string" name="data_callback">getSelectedProducts</argument>
              <argument xsi:type="string" name="hidden_input_name">products</argument>
              <argument xsi:type="string" name="reload_param_name">attachment_products</argument>
            </arguments>
          </action>
          <action method="addColumnInputName">
            <arguments>
              <argument xsi:type="string" name="input_name">position</argument>
            </arguments>
          </action>
        </reference>
      </block>
    </block>
  </body>
</page>
```

Please find code below url.
https://github.com/sivajik34/Magento2-Product-Attachments

Answer (score 1):

[The `<reference>` tag does not exist in Magento 2.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) You can use either `<referenceBlock>` or `<referenceContainer>`.

In your case as **you're declaring the block in the same layout file as the reference you don't need it.**

So you need to remove those two lines from your code:

```
<reference name="product_grid_serializer">
...
</reference>
```